# Tool to visualize launch files

Tags: ros, visualization, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering if anybody knew of a tool that could be used to visualize launch files.  Some launch files are very complex and hierarchical.  They can almost be thought of as code, they take parameters and can be very dynamic.  This complexity is hard to manage, even for launch files with which you are familiar. A graphical visualization would be great, but even something as simple as the urdf verification tools would be nice(see [here](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf#Verification) )

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122876/tool-to-visualize-launch-files/) by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1601 on 2014-01-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a tool called [rxdeveloper](http://code.google.com/p/rxdeveloper-ros-pkg/), maybe that is what you are looking for.

Also (this may sound trivial, but helps me quite a bit) in most IDEs you can choose to see the launch files as markup language, that will add colors to the otherwise black/white text.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2014-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3